# Jenkins build trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I used jenkins remote trigger build option at job A and triggered another job B. When I open job B build, I could see "Started by remote project <path to job A>". I am trying to get the value  from job B after execution but I not working. I tried working with BuildUser plugin which gave null output. Could someone help me to find a way to find the information?

Comment: What do you mean by "_get the value from job B after execution_". Which value? The build status?

Comment: I am sending mail notification post execution of job B. There are many jobs which has access to trigger job B. so when I send notification, I want to specify which job has triggered job B. I am looking for job name (job A) to be added to the notification.

Comment: I see. If you don't escape HTML entities like '<' and '>' the content will not be displayed. I corrected this accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) job setup options have a section ***Build Info*** with a field *Parameters*. Define parameters there like:

```
TRIGGERED_BY_JOB=${JOB_NAME}
TRIGGERED_BY_BUILD_NO=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

and use them accordingly in your job B.

See [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) for other available information.

Comment: I tried by adding this to my pipeline triggerRemoteJob mode: [$class: 'ConfirmScheduled', timeout: [timeoutStr: '5m'], whenTimeout: [$class: 'ContinueAsFailure']], parameterFactories: [[$class: 'SimpleString', name: 'TRIGGERED_BY_JOB', value: "${JOB_NAME}"], [$class: 'SimpleString', name: 'TRIGGERED_BY_BUILD_NO', value: "${BUILD_NUMBER}"]], remotePathUrl: 'job path' but getting error at remote job like groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TRIGGERED_BY_JOB for class: WorkflowScript . I just tried println of TRIGGERED_BY_JOB

Comment: @Eldo Open your job B config → **_General_** → ☑ _This project is parameterized_ → **_Add Parameter_** → **_String Parameter_** → _Name: TRIGGERED_BY_JOB_ and the same for _TRIGGERED_BY_BUILD_NO_.

Comment: I cannot this option as we are using template based jobs. If I use 'This project is parameterized' option from 'properties', it will remove the link between job and template after first execution.

Comment: @Eldo Which of [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin), [Template Workflows Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Template+Workflows+Plugin), [EZ Templates Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EZ+Templates+Plugin), [jobtemplates Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/jobtemplates+Plugin) do you use exactly?

Comment: job templates which provided by cloudbees.

Comment: So [this one](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/enterprise-edition/features/templates-plugin). I'm sorry, I don't use Cloudbees and this plugin isn't available in OSS Jenkins (yet?).